Create summary table of all requirements in a document generation template
I want to create a table in my "Qualification Provisions" chapter that shows the requirement Alias, name and verificationMethod tagged field for all requirements in the current package or child packages.
I am thinking a custom SQL query is needed for this, but have no idea how to go about it. How do I query the database to find all the requirements in some package?

If you create an SQL fragment template, you can use a query like this one this to get the information from all requirements in the packages being processed.
select o.Stereotype as RQType, o.Name as Requirement
, o.Note as [Description-Formatted]
from t_object o where 
o.Object_Type = 'Requirement'
and o.Package_ID = #PACKAGEID#

The macro #PACKAGEID# will be replaced by the package ID of the current package being processed.
In the template you can use the fields like this

Use {Description.Formatted} to indicate that this field contains formatted text.
